# How can I find a directory and a subdirectory and a subdirectory in linux?

Tags: linux

I am new to linux. I am trying to find a directory structure that looks like this: /org/voltdb/client.

I can find lots of [tutorials](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-a-directory-linux-command/) showing how to find a directory but none showing how to find an entire directory path.

How can I search for a particular directory hierarchy?

This does not work: find  / -type d -name "/org/voltdb/client" -ls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon Lin's solution does not work, because the '/org/voltdb/client' will not appear in the output of `find`. You should use this instead:

```
find / -type d -name 'client' | grep /org/voltdb/client
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` command. It's very versatile for searching with patterns. Try:

```
find / -type d -path '/org/voltdb/client'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just grep the output:

```
find / -type d -name 'org' | grep /org/voltdb/client
```

Comment: if that returns no results when I run it from root, does that mean the directory structure does not exist?